# PDF got generated with blank pages in Angular15

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with Angular15. I need help I struck with PDF generation with blank pages.

**Scenario:** Based on the requirement I have a download button to generate PDF in new tab. We are getting blob data from backend service. But we are unable to generate PDF with data.

**Problem:** We need to generate PDF in new tab. Also need to download one copy of file when user click on download button. But we are unable to print or generate the data in PDF. We are able to open the blank pdf in new tab.

**DownloadPDF.component.html**

```
<div class="downlaod-pdf" (click)="pdfDownlaod()">Download PDF</div>
```

**DownloadPDF.component.ts**

```
public pdfDownload(){
     this.pdfService.getPDFReport().subscribe( (res) => {
          const blob = new Blob([res], { type: 'application/pdf' });
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          window.open(url, "_blank");
        })
      }
```

Thank you

Comment: possible to provide a stackblitz with a dummy PDF where the issue happens, it will be helpful to debug

Comment: Are you should the result from service is correct? The number of pages is the expacted?